# How to restrict access to a document and all of its SUBCOLLECTIONS in FireStore based on a user group/role? (without group name in each document)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I found this nice answer to my question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57069510/13648205).

```dart
match /leagues/{league}/{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid ==
        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/leagues/$(league)).data.creator
}
```

However, I do not get it to work. My implementation looks like this:

```dart
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
        allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /employees/{user} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
 //   match /companies/{document=**} {
 //     allow read, write: if false;
 //   }
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    function getEmployeeData() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(request.auth.uid)).data
    }
    // check if the current user has access to specific company
    function accessCompany(companyId) {
      return isSignedIn() && getEmployeeData()['companyId'] == companyId;
    }
  }
  
  match /users/{user} {
    allow get: if true;
    allow list, create: if false;
    allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == user;
  }

  match /employees/{user} {
    allow get: if request.auth.uid == user || hasRole('admin');
    allow list: if hasRole('admin');
    allow update: if hasRole('admin');
    allow create, delete: if false;
  }
  
  match /companies/{company}/{document=**} {      // <<<<<<<<<<<<<< IMPLEMENTATION HERE
    allow read, write: if getEmployeeData()['companyId'] == 
      get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(company)).data.id;
        }
}
```

So with `request.auth.uid` I lookup the document id of the company document in the employees collection. Then I compare this with the id of the requested company (sub) document `companies/$(company)).data.id`.

I also tried

```dart
  match /companies/{company}/{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if getEmployeeData()['companyId'] == company;
```

Does anyone see my mistake or misunderstanding?

Comment: Security rules by themselves don't do anything.  They are only triggered when a client makes a query. Please edit the question to show the query that isn't working the way you expect with these rules, and be clear what you think it should do instead.

Comment: If you want to do more detailed debugging, you should use the local emulator: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

Comment: I am using the playground to query (get) a document. When I raised the question, there was no way to get it working. Meanwhile I used the last working version and implemented again the features. As light debugging I am now inserting constants to se which side of the equation fails. And when I enter `if getEmployeeData()['companyId'] == '4U4kZKXkr3rHA6B04S5K';` (the document id),  I now get the answer that an unknown error has occurred when running the simulation

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in detail what you're doing that doesn't work the way you expect. There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to duplicate the behavior.

Comment: Got it, the function needs to be within the same match as where it is called. Sound logical, but looked different in the article that I used as a blueprint. Now I am on track again and hopeful to get it running

Answer (score 1):

The function needs to be "anywhere upchain" from the match statement.  I use a very deep database structure, with convenience functions at many levels.  In your case, you could put the function like so:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      function getEmployeeData() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
      }
```

and it would be available to all of your other match statements.

Answer (score 0):

My [blueprint](https://blog.anoff.io/2018-08-12-rbac-firestore/) for this was quite misleading. The functions need to be located within the calling match statement. Now it works

```dart
match /companies/{company}/{document=**} {
      function getEmployeeData() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
      }
      allow read, write: if getEmployeeData()['companyId'] == company;
}
```